# Eclipse multiple bookmarks windows

Tags: eclipse, bookmarks, eclipse-neon

On Eclipse Neon 3.0, I can create multiple bookmarks windows with different names. This is very useful. There is only one problem, the content of each bookmark window (the bookmarks) are linked which means whenever I delete/add a bookmark in window1 it's being added/deleted on all the other windows.
I searched the eclipse help for a solution with vain. Does anyone know how to use multiple bookmarks windows and use them independently?
I should be able to add/remove bookmarks in window1 without altering the bookmarks in window2 (window1 and window2 are the names of my two bookmarks windows).
Thanks for the help.

Comment: How are you creating this multiple bookmark windows in the first place?

Comment: From any bookmark window, on the top left corner there is an arrow, if you click on it, you have a drop down menu where you can select "New Bookmark View" which creates a new bookmark window then ask you for a name.

Answer (score 0):

Bookmarks belong to resources not the individual bookmark view. Deleting the bookmark will always delete it everywhere.

Multiple bookmark views are only useful for using the content filter options to show different contents.

Comment: So is there any way on eclipse to have different bookmark windows each with a different set of bookmarks?

Comment: Well the View menu (the arrow menu) has a 'Configure Contents' menu where you can control the contents to some extent.